# How does c# SslStream's read() function know when to return 0?

Tags: c#, sockets, sslstream

I have an ssl client set up in c# and am currently taking steps to make sure socket reads are as reliable as they can be. The SslStream.read() documentation indicates that it returns 0 when there is no more data to read, what does that mean exactly? What if there is some lag so there is no data ready to be read? Does SslStream.read() have a built in timeout before it returns 0 or should I add some retries and what not until deciding the connection is lost?

Here is my basic workflow for receiving data.

```
ulong expected = 8;
int offset = 0;
int read = 0;
do
{
    read = sslStream.Read(buffer, offset, expected - offset);
    offset += read;
} while (offset != expected && read != 0);

expected = byte8toulong(buffer);
Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
read = 0;
offset = 0;

do
{
    // The same as above but saving the data as it comes in.
} while(offset != expected && read != 0);
```

So I guess my question is under what circumstances is read == 0? Does lag cause it to return 0? Should I add a timer / retries until I'm satisfied that the connection is hosed or does Read() already do something like that?

Comment: You may need to do some research on how streams work in general.  I'm pretty sure that failures while reading a stream, or any interruption in the connection will result in an exception.  Otherwise you read from a stream until there is nothing left to read, i.e. `Read()` returns 0.

Comment: If there is some lag it will wait for data, it will not return 0 just because of that. Read returns 0 for all streams in .NET when stream "ends", it is kind of a convention.

Comment: In TCP based communications, a zero means the other side sent a FIN, closing the sending half of the channel. The underlying network stack thus "knows" that no more data will be received.

Answer (score -3):

Socket read or write should always be able to catch exceptions (server side or client side connection goes down), wrap that in a try catch.

Keep reading if 0 received because that doesn't indicate a disconnect on either side until some kind of timeout has passed that you are willing to set. ( Exceptions will handle most of it ) but a client connection can remain open even if the server connection is down, and the server connection can remain open even if the client is down.

Comment: Needlessly colorful language aside, none of this is relevant to `SslStream`. Streams are not sockets. If `Stream.Read` returns 0, there's really not going to be any more data, even if the stream reads from a network.